# Does the price trick you? (Windscreen)

Tags: microphone

> Foam screen:
>   http://www.fotovideo.no/WebPages/Produkt/ProduktInfo.aspx?plid=68839&WebSiteMapNodeID=1000001&ref=acdc1213
>
> Dead cat:
>   http://viewitem.eim.ebay.no/WINDSCHUTZ-WINDFELL-SENNHEISER-MIKROFON-ME-66--ME66/380295316555/item

I thought dead cat windscreens [were generally considered better than foam screens](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3427/what-is-the-difference-between-a-dead-cat-and-a-foam-screen), but here you can see that the foam screen is the more expensive of the two. Why? Is the foam screen actually better than the dead cat? (The prices here can be divided by 5,7 to get USD.)

Comment: Maybe it's because the second (cheaper) link is to eBay?

Comment: @WarriorBob So you think that it's just because eBay tends to be cheaper without compromising quality?

Comment: I think it's likely that the eBay item is used, refubished, hiding behind shipping fees, or otherwise not a good comparison to retail.   I also think it's likely that quality might be compromised :) I don't read Danish though, so it's hard for me to say for sure.

Comment: So here the foamy one is actually the best (most likely)?

Comment: That's what [this answer you accepted](http://avp.stackexchange.com/a/3430/95) seems to think. I've not used either so I can't personally say for sure. I just mean to say that I'm not sure there's a discrepancy in pricing based on the links that you provided.

Comment: Huh? That answer stated that the dead cat is the best one. And that is the cheapest one here.

Comment: I misread your earlier comment, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that foam wind screen is a Senny and not an aftermarket. The dead cat pictured looks like a pretty cheapo model.

Comment: So the foam screen's build quality makes the whole screen better than the dead cat in this example?

Comment: I couldn't hazard a guess without hearing it... if you want a guess... then I would think the cheap dead cat would be better than just plain foam.